# DNA to RNA Transcription code in Python 3.6 failing 'ACGTXXXCTTAA' test

Tags: python

I am trying to solve DNA to RNA Transcription problem but my code is unable to pass this test case: `ACGTXXXCTTAA`

The transcription should be as follows:

```
G --> C

C --> G

T --> A

A --> U
```

Here's my code:

```
dna = input()
new = ""

for i in dna:
    if i not in 'ATGC':
        print("Invalid Input")
        break
    if i == 'A':
        new += 'U'
    elif i == 'C':
        new += 'G'
    elif i == 'T':
        new += 'A'
    else:
        new += 'C'

print(new)
```

This code passes all tests except aforementioned one. The correct output should be:

```
Invalid Input
```

The output my code gives:

```
Invalid Input
UGCA
```

I have tried many iterations but I cannot get rid of `UGCA`. Even though I use `break` to get out of the loop in case of any `Invalid Input` the code is able to transcribe `ACGT` before `XXX` and print the result when it should just output `Invalid Input`.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always print new so instead using `print("Invalid Input")` you can simply change the value of new to 'Invalid Input' and print. That should fix your problem!

```
dna = input()
new = ""

for i in dna:
    if i not in 'ATGC':
        new = "Invalid Input"
        break
    if i == 'A':
        new += 'U'
    elif i == 'C':
        new += 'G'
    elif i == 'T':
        new += 'A'
    else:
        new += 'C'

print(new)
```

Comment: Perhaps OP thinks that `break` ends the entire program, rather than just the for loop.

Comment: This works perfectly, but leads to a bit of weirdness when used as a general solution. What if the arbitrary sequence (and mapping) you're decoding allows for the sequence `"Invalid Input"` to be a valid result? It makes more sense to me to use exception handling for this, but YMMV :)

Comment: @AdamSmith if i was using this in a business or research setting i'd probably go with something else, but this seems to be more of a learning programming assignment, and a simple misunderstanding of how the break/printing works in the program. My solution was more towards helping OP learn then providing the best solution. Your solution and bphi's solution are both better from a technical stand point

Comment: @GrantWilliams agreed, and there's certainly nothing wrong with doing it your way in Python! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a neat problem because it introduces so many concepts at once! Your direct problem is that even when you throw the `Invalid Input` error, you still print `new` which is the partially transcribed sequence. To fix that, you could have your error handling code throw an exception, or simply blank out the result. I would probably turn this into a function and throw an exception.

```
def dna_to_rna(dna):
    acc = []
    for ch in dna:
        if ch not in 'ATGC':
            raise ValueError("Invalid Input")
        if ch == 'A':
            acc.append('U')
        # ... and etc for each alternation
    return ''.join(acc)  # return the correct complete sequence
                         # only after all characters are processed

try:
    result = dna_to_rna(whatever_sequence)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

However this is also a great case to use a dictionary for lookups, rather than a big long `if/elif/else` block

```
mapping = {'A': 'U',
           'C': 'G',
           'T', 'A',
           'G', 'C'}
try:
    result = ''.join([mapping.get(ch) for ch in dna])
except TypeError:
    # if any member of `dna` is not ATCG, it will try to `''.join` over
    # a None value, which throws a TypeError
    print("Invalid Input")
else:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this for brevity and clarity

```
DNA_TO_RNA_MAP = {'G': 'C', 'C': 'G', 'T': 'A', 'A': 'U'}

dna = input()

if any(base not in DNA_TO_RNA_MAP.keys() for base in dna):
    print('Invalid Input')
else: 
    print(''.join(DNA_TO_RNA_MAP[base] for base in dna))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new = ''
dna = input()

for i in dna:
    if i not in "GCTA":
        print('Invalid Input')
        break
else:
    for j in dna:
        if j == 'G':
            new += 'C'
        elif j == 'C':
            new +='G'
        elif j == 'T':
            new +='A'
        elif j == 'A':
            new +='U'
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
print(new)
```

Comment: Good code! Consider adding an explanation of how it works and what the main difference is between your code and theirs that fixes their issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
b=input()
a="GCTA"
c="CGAU"
try:print(''.join([c[a.index(i)]for i in b]))
except:print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 0):

path = input('\nEnter the file path...\n\n')

with open(path, 'r') as file:
dna = file.read()

mrna = dna.upper().translate(str.maketrans('CGAT', 'GCUA'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).